# Why doesn't `sudo cd /var/named` work?

Tags: permissions, sudo

I want to `cd` into `/var/named` but it gives me a permission denied error, and when I want to use `sudo` to do this I am not permitted. What is the technical reason for this, and is it possible to do this some other way?

Answer (score 342, accepted):

The reason you can't do this is simple and two fold

#### 1

`cd` is not a program but an in-built command and `sudo` only applies to programs.

`sudo foo` means run the program foo as root

`sudo cd /path` returns

```
sudo: cd: command not found
```

because `cd` is not a program.

#### 2

If it were possible to use **sudo** to `cd` to a protected directory then having run the command `sudo cd /var/named` you would be in that directory as a normal user but normal users are not allowed to be in that directory.

**This is not possible.**

**Workaround:**

You can use `sudo -i` to elevate yourself to super user. For example:

```
sudo -i
cd /var/named
```

You are now logged on as root and can use whatever commands you wish. When finished type `exit` and you are back to being logged on as a normal user.

Comment: Technically `cd` is both a builtin and an external command. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command

Comment: @kojiro Ubuntu does not; at least in a clean install; have `/usr/bin/cd` only the built in

Comment: Regarding point 2: If you `sudo -i` (or `sudo su`) then `cd /var/named` and then `su normaluser`... can you do that?

Comment: @AlvinWong Why not try it and find out?  Just tested if you `sudo -i` then `cd` to a directory you should not be in the `su normal_user` then `pwd` shows you are in the protected directory but `ls` does not work `ls: cannot open directory.: permission denied`

Comment: Workaround worked.

Comment: then why does `sudo echo` work, when it is also a `shell builtin`  like the cd

Comment: @BalmanRawat [`sudo echo` runs `/bin/echo` instead of the `echo` shell builtin.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960822/why-is-there-a-bin-echo-and-why-would-i-want-to-use-it)

Answer (score 33):

That's because `cd` is not an executable, it's a shell function to change directory.

If you run:

```
type cd
```

your will get:

> cd is a shell function

You can use `sudo -s` to open an interactive shell and then `cd` to to your desired directory:

```
sudo -s
cd /var/named
```

To return back to your normal shell simply hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: As you cannot use `sudo cd foo`, you cannot use `sudo type foo` too, as it's a shell built-in.

Answer (score 26):

All of the answers above are correct; here's a workaround though

```
sudo sh -c "cd restricted-dir; some_command"
```

Comment: I like this solution best because you do your root stuff, then return immediately to non-root mode so you don't forget and make Big Mistakes.

Comment: this command didnt work for me

Answer (score 18):

It's also worth remembering that, `cd`'s status as a shell builtin or external binary notwithstanding, **sudo works by spawning a new process to run the command specified**.

Why is this important? Because the basic execution flow of sudo becomes something very similar to this:

1. The shell spawns off a subprocess to run sudo with the given parameters
2. sudo authenticates the user and confirms their right to execute the specified command
3. sudo spawns off a subprocess to execute the specified command
4. sudo waits for the subprocess spawned off in step 3 to exit
5. sudo exits, returning to the shell
6. The subprocess spawed in step 1 exits, returning the user to the shell prompt

(This *may* be *technically* slightly incorrect; there is a system call which actually *replaces* the running process with a new one (that's the C library's `execve()`). However, for the purposes of this explanation, the two are equivalent.)

This becomes important when you consider that the current working directory is a property of each process and is *inherited but not promoted*. So if process A spawns off a new process B, then process B starts with the same working directory that process A was in. (This is why something as mundane as `ls ./` does what you'd expect.) But if process B changes *its* working directory, then unless process A goes out of its way looking for that, A is completely unaware of that change. (This, in turn, is why if you run something like `find /` and abort it half-way through, you don't end up in some seemingly random location in the file system just because find happened to be looking there at the moment it was aborted.)

So even if `sudo cd /somewhere` did exactly what it says on the tin, by the time `sudo` exits, you are brought right back where you started. Hence effectively from the point of view of the user, it becomes a no-op. The fact that `cd`, while it was executing, called the `chdir()` system library function to set a new working directory, doesn't help you, the user.

As [Warren Hill](https://askubuntu.com/a/291677/11751) pointed out, **the proper solution** (I actually wouldn't call it a workaround) is to use `sudo -i` which drops you to a root shell where you can navigate around the filesystem freely and execute whatever commands you feel like. Do note however that when you exit this shell, you are *still* brought right back where you started in the directory hierarchy for exactly the same reason as I described above.

Comment: This explanation was nice and your bit about "So even if `sudo cd /somewhere` did exactly what it says on the tin, by the time `sudo` exits, you are brought back where you started." was helpful.  +1

Answer (score 4):

You can also change the permission temporarily if you are a sudo user.

sudo chmod 0775 path

or

sudo chmod +r folderpath

Make sure you put it back if necessary.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: I don't have the right to run an interactive shell with sudo, so this is quite the way to go..