# How to edit /boot/efi

Tags: boot, dual-boot, files, refind, restricted-access

I have installed rEFInd, and it works well enough, but I am trying to add a theme. To do so, I need access to the /boot/efi/ folder. When I try to access it, I get the following error:

```
rufio1337@BattleStation:/$ cd boot/efi
bash: cd: boot/efi: Permission denied
```

(As sudo):

```
rufio1337@BattleStation:/$ sudo cd boot/efi
sudo: cd: command not found
```

---

In the GUI it shows the folder with an x on it.

Anybody know how I can get access to this folder?

---

Running fdisk -l gives me the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 29D3E65C-B559-44C9-A9E9-A1FFEA5BA586

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type

/dev/sda1        2048    1640447    1638400  800M Windows recovery environment

/dev/sda2     1640448    2172927     532480  260M EFI System

/dev/sda3     2172928    2435071     262144  128M Microsoft reserved

/dev/sda4     2435072 3878256639 3875821568  1.8T Microsoft basic data

/dev/sda5  3878258688 3907028991   28770304 13.7G Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5c74ae42


Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type

/dev/sdb1              63 347550949 347550887 165.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

/dev/sdb2       347551742 488396799 140845058  67.2G  5 Extended

/dev/sdb5       347551744 463405055 115853312  55.2G 83 Linux

/dev/sdb6       463407104 488396799  24989696  11.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: I would also like to point out that I am veeery new to Linux, so child-speak is appreciated!

Comment: `cd /boot/efi` is correct. But if you are new, I do not recomment to start with efi themes ;-)

Comment: You also have to be root sudo -I maybe work fine.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu. They changed the mount in fstab from defaults to umask=0077 which locks it. I had to change back to defaults. And just remounting did not work. I had to reboot. `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

Comment: Not a duplicate but related to 1st problem [Why doesn't `sudo cd /var/named` work?](http://askubuntu.com/q/291666/107450)

Answer (score 4):

You can't [use sudo with cd](https://superuser.com/questions/241129/why-wont-sudo-cd-work). To get into protected directories, you can type

```
sudo bash
```

To get a root login shell or type

```
su -
```

To log in as root in your current shell. The behavior of both is identical, the back end differences won't matter much for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is necro'ing your question but an alternatively way you could do this is with `gnome-system-monitor`

In the terminal type `sudo gnome-system-monitor` which will open a gui that shows running processes, active resources, and file systems.

Click file systems then open the /boot/efi

Since the gui was opened with root permissions, the file window is granted root permissions as well.

You can edit files you need or you can continue your journey with root privileges by right clicking the window and selecting `open in terminal`.