# How can I access anbox filesystem?

Tags: mount, filesystem, anbox

I know anbox is still unstable, i installed the latest version of anbox in ubuntu 16.04 and it works fine but it seems i cant save or download files in the anbox filesystem. I noticed anbox installation created a volumen of 326Mb where there is a folder called storage but it is read only file system. I've tried to remount the volumen as rw and other commands to make it read and write, the comand runs but i cant access the filesystem it is alway read only. In resume i want to save/dowload files in the anbox filesystem so i can acces them via "files" in the anbox application manager. thank you

Comment: got any solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the filesystem folder:

```
/var/snap/anbox
```

And here is i.e. the "Download" folder:

```
/var/snap/anbox/common/data/media/0/Download
```

Comment: If you get access denied you need to elevate your user status to super user using `sudo -i`. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/291677/1034342)

Answer (score 1):

If you installed anbox via `apt install anbox` instead of using the snap, then you will find all files under `/var/lib/anbox/rootfs` while anbox is running. If you are interested in the contents of `/var/lib/anbox/rootfs/data`, then those are also available without anbox running under `/var/lib/anbox/data`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to install a file explorer from android (such as FX File Explorer or ES File Explorer) and then save your files and folders in a place you can access from the mounted drive.

Alternatively, you could use the same cloud service on both the linux machine and Anbox. For example, by using Google Drive with ES File Explorer, I was able to do the following:

- Create a word file using Word Mobile and save it on Google Drive from Anbox.
- Work on it from there.
- Notice the integration between the two file systems.