# Folder: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive, mac, hfs+

I am using Ubuntu and want access and copy all data from this external HDD:

```
/dev/sdb2: UUID="aa6741de-df88-308f-b894-4b67c163b8b3" LABEL="Macintosh HD" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="Customer" PARTUUID="00003b28-10f7-0000-251a-00004a5b0000"
```

For some folders permission is denied:

```
peace@ubunt:/media/peace/Macintosh HD/Users$ sudo chown peace "/media/peace/Macintosh HD/Users/Christine"/
chown: changing ownership of '/media/peace/Macintosh HD/Users/Christine/': Read-only file system
peace@ubunt:/media/peace/Macintosh HD/Users$ cd Christine
bash: cd: Christine: Permission denied
```

Please tell me how can I access and copy the folder Christine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can access folders with elevated privileges using sudo from a terminal.

1. Open a terminal
2. type `sudo cp '/media/peace/Macintosh HD/Users/Christine/' ~/Christine/`
3. Now all the contents of the folder are copied to the `~/Christine/` folder.

If you still cannot access the copied files, you could use `sudo chown -R peace:ubunt ~/Christine/*` to change file ownership

Answer (score 1):

You can read all the files and folders as a superuser. However, you cannot modify anything on an HFS+ drive because Ubuntu’s HFS+ driver does not support writing.

## Use `sudo`

While you cannot `cd` to the folder (and [`sudo cd` never works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291666/why-doesnt-sudo-cd-var-named-work)), you should be able to `sudo ls`:

```
peace@ubunt:/media/peace/Macintosh HD/Users$ sudo ls Christine
```

And as [@ToDo noted](https://askubuntu.com/a/1158743/250300), you can also `sudo cp` data from the HFS+ drive and perform other read operations.

## Use a root shell

You can also directly switch to root (superuser) shell and use `cd` and other commands as normally.

**Attention:** As root, you can do anything, including harmful things. Be very careful when issuing commands in the root shell. Type `exit` to return to your normal shell.

```
$ sudo -i
# cd Christine
```